# How to update row in table with condition is refer to another table

Tags: spring, database, hibernate, single-page-application

How can I update a table which the condition is refer to other table in spring jpa ?
I have table Task which relation to TaskProgress (many to one). And TaskProgress has some value eg: CREATE, INPROGRES, DONE, ARCHIVED,...
Here is my query in repostitory:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Task t  SET t.responsibleUser = null WHERE t.responsibleUser.id = :userId " +
            "AND t.deleted = false AND t.taskProgress.name <> 'ARCHIVED'")
void removeResponsibleUserId(UUID userId);
```

But I got the error:

```
Hibernate: update task cross join  set responsible_user_id=null where responsible_user_id=? and deleted=0 and name<>'ARCHIVED'
2020-11-25 00:38:51 - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2020-11-25 00:38:51 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set responsible_user_id=null where responsible_user_id=x'152B59C33A0035003500000' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an exists predicate like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Task t  SET t.responsibleUser = null WHERE t.responsibleUser.id = :userId " +
       "AND t.deleted = false AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t.taskProgress p WHERE p.name = 'ARCHIVED')")
void removeResponsibleUserId(UUID userId);
```